# ActionScript 3 isn't supposed to be a simple synchronous architecture language?

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, trace, synchronous

A simple piece of code that should trace :

- rien
- test
- done!

and I get something completely far away from that,

scenario A :

```
var __functions_to_execute:Array;

function start():void {
    __functions_to_execute  =[];

    __functions_to_execute.push(futile_trace());
    __functions_to_execute.push(futile_trace('test'));

    execute_functions();
}

function execute_functions():void {
    if(__functions_to_execute.length){
        //where shift on this Array remove the first element and returns it
        var exec:Function =__functions_to_execute.shift();
        exec;

        //I tried this too, just in case
        //__functions_to_execute[0];
        //__functions_to_execute.shift();
    } else  trace("done!");
}

function futile_trace(_value:String ='rien'):void {
    trace(_value);
    execute_functions();
}

start();
```

pretty simple.  but the result is :

- rien
- done!
- test

lets add a deprecated function to this and lets change the futile_trace function to :

```
function futile_trace(_value:String ='rien'):void {
    trace(_value);
    setTimeout(execute_functions, 0);
}
```

and then the result is :

- rien
- test
- done!

Ok then, I said to myself, why not, lets change the scope when I call execute_functions, so I tried :

```
function futile_trace(_value:String ='rien'):void {
    trace(_value);
    extra_step();
}

function extra_step():void {
    execute_functions();
}
```

guess what was the result?!  yeah :

- rien
- done!
- test

so?! Is the trace function that bad? that slow? is it the fact that passing an argument to the function take so much time compare to the other one?  I mean... wow!

is there something I can do to avoid this type of weirdness ?

(For the record, my project is not to trace {rien, done and test}... I have 15k lines of codes that react completely differently if I compile them with "Omit trace statements" or not.

Thanks for your input guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing the functions and adding their return values to the `__functions_to_execute` array, not the functions themselves.

Your function `execute_functions` doesn't actually do anything. I've tried to explain the sequence in-line:

```
function start():void {
    __functions_to_execute  =[];
    // 1. traces 'rien' first because futile_trace() is called with no args
    // 2. 'done!' will be traced inside execute_functions because the array is still empty
    // 3.undefined will be pushed into the array next
    __functions_to_execute.push(futile_trace());
    // 4. traces 'test'
    // execute_functions does not trace anything because __functions_to_execute is non-empty
    // but it also doesn't do anything because it is just removing the `undefined` value from the start of the array.
    __functions_to_execute.push(futile_trace('test'));

    execute_functions();
}
```

Something more like this should behave how you expect. It's storing in the array function references, along with the arguments that should be passed when the function is called.

```
var __functions_to_execute:Array;

function start():void {
    __functions_to_execute = [];

    __functions_to_execute.push({func:futile_trace, args:[]});
    __functions_to_execute.push({func:futile_trace, args:['test']});

    execute_functions();
}

function execute_functions():void {
    if(__functions_to_execute.length){
        var obj:Object = __functions_to_execute.shift();
        obj.func.apply(null, obj.args);
    } else  trace("done!");
}

function futile_trace(_value:String ='rien'):void {
    trace(_value);
    execute_functions();
}

start();
```

Comment: Thanks man, it make so much sense now, trying to store the function using his literal form will call the function and store the result (void) into the array and not the actual function!

Damn, ok, so I will continue these test using array of pairs (func, args)

Comment: @Francis using a debugger helps too.

Comment: The code I was proposing seems so simple, that I was suspecting trace or other weird asynchronous event to occur. But you're right, I should use the debug.   

Speaking of debug, I will ask another question here : My final project is a stand alone application running in firefox 3.0 on Linux with flash player 10.0.  Which tools should I use to bebug the flash container running as a file (no apache running, we just play the flash straight from a local path into firefox)?   Any suggestion welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For scenario A, you're not actually ever pushing futile_trace to the array - you're calling it (notice the `()` after the function name), and then pushing the *result* of that call to the array.

In other words:

1. You call `futile_trace()`
2. `futile_trace` traces **'rien'**, because you passed no value.
3. `futile_trace` calls `_execute_functions`
4. At this point, nothing has been pushed yet, so `_execute_functions` traces **'done!'**
5. `_execute_functions` returns.
6. `_futile_trace` returns.
7. The result of `futile_trace()` (void) is pushed.
8. You call `futile_trace('test')`
9. `futile_trace()` outputs **'test'**.
10. `futile_trace` calls `_execute_functions`
11. `_execute_functions` shifts `void` from the array.
12. `_execute_functions` executes `void;` (which does nothing)
13. etc. etc.

If you need to pass a function to another function or store a reference to it in a variable, make sure you're not calling it.

```
__functions_to_execute.push(futile_trace);
// Use an anonymous function to pass with arguments without executing:
__functions_to_execute.push(function() { futile_trace('test'); });
```

... and in `_execute_functions` *do* remember the parantheses:

```
exec();
```

Comment: Both answer are good, Thanks for your help!  Unfortunately I can only assign one good answer!  But thanks for your explanation!

:)

Comment: No worries - I had a bit of Javascript-think in there anyway (undefined), which is fixed now. ;-)